# Custom notification not working in Android 8

Tags: android, android-notifications, custom-notification

I am using this tutorial: [Android custom notification](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/) for developing and android application with custom notifications.
Although this app runs perfectly on android 7 and below, but I am unable to run it on android 8 on my onpePlus 3T. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial is outdated. If you targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) you must create at least one notification channel.

Read official notification guide for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels

Comment: Yes. Just check if device os version is 8.0+ and then set Notification Channel.